# How to create pareto chart in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I am new to power bi and I want to create pareto chart for the data which has Total budget, actual spend by month and open commitment...What I want to do is to show budget leftover in the graph for example

In the starting of the year I have full budget so I want show as

Jan = (Total Budget - Jan open commitment)---Leftover

Now in feb I will have Jan actual spend so

Feb = (Leftover - Jan actulas - Feb open commitment)----leftover1

March = (Leftover2 - Feb actuals - March open commitment )----leftover3

and so on till Dec

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There are a couple built-in line and column chart options in Power BI. What exactly is the part you need help with?

Comment: I need to create a Pareto Chart so that I can show my leftover budget after every month and in the end of the year

Comment: I need calculation like -Jan = (Total Budget - Jan open commitment)---Leftover

Now in feb I will have Jan actual spend so

Feb = (Leftover - Jan actulas - Feb open commitment)----leftover1

March = (Leftover2 - Feb actuals - March open commitment )----leftover3

and so on till Dec
but not sure how to get that